# How to prevent image moving when resizing window

Tags: css, css-float, collision, fluid

Im currently developing this site http://digitalgenesis.com.au/projects/sister/music.html

What happens when i re-size screen is that it eventually collides with the div contents holding page title and then jumps down a line into the wrong position

http://digitalgenesis.com.au/projects/sister/img/screen.png

What i'd like to do is have it stop just before it hits the text on the page

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to do this

Here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/reset.css" />
       <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">


<div id="musicbox">
<div id="musicheader">Music</div>

<div id="musicline"></div>
<div id="musiccontent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris accumsan nunc vel odio faucibus euismod. Nulla semper lorem vel risus volutpat congue. Sed eleifend velit eget mauris luctus in imperdiet eros ultricies. Ut et gravida ligula. Vestibulum placerat placerat bibendum. Vestibulum pretium mollis arcu, et pharetra est sagittis sed. Vestibulum facilisis elementum urna vel fermentum. Vestibulum id metus at magna tristique ornare in id lorem. Nulla rhoncus, neque ac scelerisque varius, felis enim convallis ipsum, sed auctor libero dolor in ligula. Vivamus rhoncus, sapien non feugiat tempus, tortor enim euismod dolor, ac placerat ante enim sed diam. </div>
</div>


</div>

<div id="musicimg"><img src="img/katrina.jpg" alt="#" /></div>



</body>
</html>
```

And the css is

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CodeLightRegular';
    src: url('../fonts/code/code_light_copy-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/code/code_light_copy-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/code/code_light_copy-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/code/code_light_copy-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/code/code_light_copy-webfont.svg#CodeLightRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}


#wrap{width:960px; margin:0 auto;}



#musicheader{font-size:120px; font-family: 'CodeLightRegular'; }
#musicbox{float:left; width:519px; }
#musicline{height:4px; background:black;  }
#musicimg{float:right; width:441px; }
#musiccontent{width:120%;}

#clear{clear:both;}
```

Comment: Have you considered making her a background-image of the body and positioned in the top right with no-repeat, rather than as an image element in the page?

Comment: i'd still want the text to expand out with the page, assuming i put width percentages for the text divs it should expand out without overlapping the image correct?

Comment: @user828919 The text would overlap the image when the window gets too small. I'd suggest you put a background color where you have text if you are going the background image way.

Comment: thnx dan, ill use that method and see what i come up with

Comment: heres the updated link http://digitalgenesis.com.au/projects/sistercopy/music.html

Comment: just out of curiosity is there a simple way to work around it using the positioning tag on div elements? if i were to use a div rather then the background image method i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a HTML5 solution would be to use media queries to style the page differently depending on width:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/base.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 960px)" href="css/main.css" />
```

in your `base.css` you would have all the common styling plus any styling for smaller screens. In your `main.css` you would have overrides for the larger screen.

*(In other words you need to design your css with the small screen in mind first and then add css to make it look nice on larger screens.)*

**UPDATE:-**

For example try:

```
@media screen
{
  body{
      background-size: 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 645px)
{
  body{
      background-size: 20%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 960px)
{
  body{
      background-size: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the support and recommendation, ill see what i can come up with

Comment: @user828919 If I wasn't specific enough let me know. Sometimes I assume everyone understands me.

Comment: I've updated the page @ digitalgenesis.com.au/projects/sistercopy/music.html. However now i cant scroll down at all on the page. For the css i added background-position: right top; Thanks for the support so far, I'm only new to development

Comment: @user828919 that is because the background image is not part of the "flow". Which means it has no height. I personally like it better this way as scrollbars annoy me especially when there is no real content. You could make it scroll by setting a height and overflow:auto; on your `<body>` element, but as I don't think it needs it. Also it looks like you haven't got any media queries with `min-width` on your site, which would fix the background issue going behind the text.

Comment: cheers for the info about possible height fix on scrollbar and i'll definitely code in the min-width for page. just making minor changes and making sure they are cross browser friendly first.

Comment: @user828919 IE8 and earlier will have issues with min-height/width and some media queries.

Comment: im having some issues getting min-width working on firefox.  css is @ http://digitalgenesis.com.au/projects/sistercopy/css/main.css. woulda thought 1 of those min-width values would of worked at least

Comment: Don't specify both a `width` and a `min-width` I don't think that works. Also it wasn't the `min-width` I was refering to. http://www.broken-links.com/2011/02/21/using-media-queries-in-the-real-world/

Comment: Thanks so much, should of read up. Will make another css for smaller screen and see how it goes

Comment: Just to clarify, is the update provided above for internal stylesheet tags? I've created 3 separate stylesheets to simulate 3 widths auto, min-height 645px and min-height 960px. Could you shoot through a message if I've got the right idea?

Comment: @user828919 you can do it either way. Personnally i like the way you said that you're doing it. Seems to keep things neater.

Answer (score 0):

as dan said you can use it as a `background image` with `background-position; top:0; right:0; no-repeat` & said your want that the text is not overlap  the image for that you can give `min-width`